# How to show all IPs of network interfaces using "ifconfig"?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, ifconfig

I am using the Kali Linux distribution and I came across this issue that I can't solve: when I type the command `ifconfig` in the terminal I get the following network interface infos:

[image]

As you can see `lo` and `wlan0` have their IP addresses shown in the red boxes.

However `eth0` and `wlan1` do not show their IP addresses.

My goal is to have for all the network interfaces (`eth0`, `lo`, `wlan0`, `wlan1`) all the informations including `inet addr`, `Mask`, `inet6 addr` and `Scope`.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that eth0 and wlan1 have an IP address to begin with?

Comment: you were right... once I figured out how to connect wlan1 to the internet I got the IP addresses I needed... now all looks as should be!